# Datetime xaxis in high charts showing extra labels

Tags: datetime, highcharts

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  maxZoom: 14 * 24 * 3600000,
  dateTimeLabelFormats:{
    day: '%e-%b-%Y',
    week: '%e-%b-%Y',
    month: '%b \'%Y',
    year: '%Y'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Days'
  },
  labels: {
    y: 40,
    rotation: 60                          
  },    
  tickmarkPlacement:'on',
  startOnTick: true,
  endOnTick: true
}
```

I have added a column chart using high chart gallery. I used xaxis as datetime type. This chart shows previous 30 days report. I am giving a starting date to it but when chart is rendered its showing 1 or 2 extra dates in starting and same in ending. Ex- if I am giving 1 may as a starting date it should show from 1 may to 30 may but its showing from 30 apr to 1 june or 30 apr to 31 may?

Comment: please help me in this asap i have tried by removing startOnTick and endOnTick option

Comment: can we see you data source ????????

Comment: There isn't enough information here - could you add a bit more code?